# RRAS server in azure and S2S VPN

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

If I deploy RRAS server in azure and also have file server, domain controller etc. How can I create S2S VPN connection with this config. What will I need on prem to create a tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure VM, RRAS role is not supported and hence it is not recommended for Production work loads.

Here is the reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines